# Why does not flutter app run on IOS device?

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am receiving below mentioned error while running app on IOS. i am able to run app on android but not on IOS device. There is no any issue while running on the android emulator or device but it doesnot work either in IOS emulator or on an iphone

```
Pubspec.yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.5 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  curved_navigation_bar:
  firebase_core:
  firebase_auth:
  cloud_firestore:
  webview_flutter_plus:
  audioplayers: ^0.20.1
  marquee: ^2.2.3
  carousel_slider:
  page_transition:
  swipe_deck:
  custom_navigator: ^0.3.0
  provider: ^6.0.3
  flutter_neumorphic: ^3.2.0
  path_provider:
  flutter_downloader: ^1.7.0
  dio:
  permission_handler: ^8.1.6
```

Error

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-08-21 22:21:17.512 xcodebuild[97752:28385663] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-08-21 22:21:17.513 xcodebuild[97752:28385663] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Error (Xcode): redefinition of module 'Firebase'
/Users/aresrana/StudioProjects/divya/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/module.modulemap:0:7

```
Error (Xcode): could not build module 'Flutter'
/Users/aresrana/StudioProjects/divya/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8

Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/aresrana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bhnsvmbmirzxibanpfwznxueyccp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_Q1P2N8WP645E-clang_8RMZX2ZNX0IS.pch' for bridging header '/Users/aresrana/StudioProjects/divya/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and include the `pubspec.yaml`?

Answer (score 0):

Open the xcworkspace file in Xcode.. Add the Google-services.plist file from Xcode. Please delete Podfile.lock, Pods folder and .symlinks folder. Go to the iOS directory in terminal and run `pod install`.  Then in Xcode go to product and select clean build folder. Then run the project from Xcode and  all consecutive build can be done from your IDE

Comment: Error (Xcode): redefinition of module 'Firebase'
/Users/aresrana/StudioProjects/divya/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/module.modulemap:0:7 Error (Xcode): could not build module 'Flutter'
/Users/aresrana/StudioProjects/divya/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8
Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/aresrana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bhnsvmbmirzxibanpfwznxueyccp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_Q1P2N8WP645E-clang_8RMZX2ZNX0IS.pch' for bridging header '/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'

Comment: In build phase in Xcode do you have `For install builds only` checked? if yes please uncheck it